# Query multiple tables with google visualization api

Tags: jquery, sql, google-visualization

**Issue:** Currently my code works perfectly from drawing data out of one table, but what I want to do is draw that same data out of multiple google tables.

**My attempt:** I have tried different variations of the query but the table just doesn't show up when I have multiple table IDS in there.

**Working Query:**

```
var query = "SELECT 'City', 'Name', 'Gender', 'Full Address', 'Phone', 'Fax' " + 'FROM 117_2OT0fNljnKrx40V76XuoIFIm-IK6e5Zf3N2o';
```

**Attempt:** (the FROM part of the query is the part that changes)

```
 var query = "SELECT 'City', 'Name', 'Gender', 'Full Address', 'Phone', 'Fax' " + 'FROM "117_2OT0fNljnKrx40V76XuoIFIm-IK6e5Zf3N2o", "1npicUMaGTzjeDuvaDeq_F07V0Flmo1I3y3agGAc", "1BW-kAdtSNggLYOjGKeemSDRCj2eG0VF6R8wLX9w", "1yHhe0GkTBReuFdXelbAeqLzhknnNbs4JdAspndM", "1mfmx02FN7E3_G9J2BHv9FayK-UCz5BuFcxJ6j3A"';
```

**Whole google visualization code:**

```
  google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['table'] });
  function drawTable() { 
  var query = "SELECT 'City', 'Name', 'Gender', 'Full Address', 'Phone', 'Fax' " + 'FROM 117_2OT0fNljnKrx40V76XuoIFIm-IK6e5Zf3N2o'; 
  var state = document.getElementById('state').value; 

  if (state) { query += " WHERE 'State' = '" + state + "'"; } 
  var queryText = encodeURIComponent(query);
  var gvizQuery = new google.visualization.Query( 'http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=' + queryText); 

  gvizQuery.send(function(response) { 
  var table = new google.visualization.Table( document.getElementById('visualization')); 
  table.draw(response.getDataTable(), { showRowNumber: false,           sortAscending: true,            sortColumn: 0 }); 
  });

  } google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Query API for Fusion Tables is SQL-like, but is not *not* SQL-compatible.  If you want to handle table joins, you have to run multiple queries and use the [google.visualization.data.join](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google_visualization_data_join) method.  Here's a basic framework you could use to join together the results from 5 tables:

```
var url = 'http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=';
var q1 = new google.visualization.Query(url);
q1.setQuery('SELECT <columns from table 1> FROM <table 1 id>');
q1.send(function (r1) {
    var data1 = r1.getDataTable();

    var q2 = new google.visualization.Query(url);
    q2.setQuery('SELECT <columns from table 2> FROM <table 2 id>');
    q2.send(function (r2) {
        var data2 = r2.getDataTable();

        var q3 = new google.visualization.Query(url);
        q3.setQuery('SELECT <columns from table 3> FROM <table 3 id>');
        q3.send(function (r3) {
            var data3 = r3.getDataTable();

            var q4 = new google.visualization.Query(url);
            q4.setQuery('SELECT <columns from table 4> FROM <table 4 id>');
            q4.send(function (r4) {
                var data2 = r4.getDataTable();

                var q5 = new google.visualization.Query(url);
                q5.setQuery('SELECT <columns from table 5> FROM <table 5 id>');
                q5.send(function (r5) {
                    var data5 = r5.getDataTable();

                    var join1 = google.visualization.data.join(
                        data1,
                        data2,
                        <join method>,
                        [[<key column in data 1>, <matching key column in data 2>] /* etc */],
                        [<non-key columns from data 1>],
                        [<non-key columns from data 2>]
                    );
                    // repeat to join all tables together
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: That depends entirely upon the structure of each table you are querying from, and how they relate to one another.